# Where do I detect where the outlet is from in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded [a project from GitHub](https://github.com/codeaholicshk/swift-ios-sample-walkthrough-tutorial-pan-transition) and I'm experiencing some problems when detecting where a referencing outlet comes from.

This is an `UIImage` called "backgroundImage".

[image: img]

This is a `UIViewController` called "WalkthroughPageContentViewController".

[image: imgUI]

"backgroundImages" has two outlets references, one of which is connected to the "WalkthroughPageContentViewController" `UIViewController`.

[image: img2]

But there isn't any `@IBOutlet` connection here.

[image: img3]

So where does the first referencing outlet come from?

Comment: As you can see there are two referencing outlets. You can find the second one in the ViewController.swift file, but what about the first one?

Comment: It looks to me like there isn't. This sometimes happens when you remove code while there's still an outlet defined in the nib. At the top of the WalkthroughPageContentViewController in Interface Builder should be a little yellow button (the rightmost of the three.) If you right click on it, what do you see? Is there an outlet for backgroundImage? Is there an error? (Also, how do you know that this project is ready to use? Where did you come across it?)

Comment: @MattGibson Thank you for answering my question. I published a little gif that may help you understanding the problem. I hope I clarified things a bit. When I click on the yellow button a list of outlets shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look at this project, and the answer is that the referencing outlet doesn't come from anywhere. It's broken. If you examine the destination, the you'll see that Xcode knows this is a problem:

[image: Storyboard Error]

And if you open up the WalkthroughPageContentViewController.swift file, and *add* an outlet called `backgroundImage`, then close and reopen the file, you'll find it's magically been linked back up to the Storyboard:

[image: Magic!]

So, I'd surmise that at some point, there *was* an outlet in the file called `backgroundImage`, which was hooked up to the Storyboard, but then it was later deleted, leaving the project in this state.

This is pretty common when editing projects in Xcode. The Storyboard connections are basically just stored in XML in the .xib file, and there's no magic two-way connection between them and the code at design time, so if you delete the lines of code that they point to, you'll end up in this state.